# How to prove $f^{-1} (B' \cap B'') = (\neq) f^{-1}(B' ) \cap f^{-1}(B'') $

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I know that
$$f^{-1} (B' \cap B'') = \{a \in A | f(a) \in B' \cap B'' \} = \{a \in A | f(a) \in B' \wedge f(a) \in B''\} $$
On the other hand
$$f^{-1}(B') \cap f^{-1}(B'') = \{ a \in A | f(a) \in B' \} \cap \{ a \in A | f(a) \in B''\}$$
But I don' t know what to do next

Comment: RHS1 equals RHS2, so you are allowed to conclude that LHS1 equals LHS2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

It is true in general that:
$$\{a\in A\mid P(a)\}\cap\{a\in A\mid Q(a)\}=\{a\in A\mid P(a)\wedge Q(a)\}$$

This can be proved on elementary way.

Comment: But I know that $f(A' \cap A'') \neq f(A') \cap f(A'').$ Do you can help me to prove this?

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand how to prove $f(A' \cap A'') \neq f(A') \cap f(A'')$. I think that both of these facts proved the same way, but i know that it's false

Comment: Just let $f$ be a constant function and let $A'$ and $A''$ be non-empty and disjoint. Then LHS is empty and RHS is $\{c\}$ where $c$ denotes constant value of $f$.

Comment: Images and preimages of a function $f$ are essentially different. Lots of equalities where it concerns preimages and lots of inequalities where it concerns images. Drop the unfruitful idea that facts concerning images and preimages are proved the same way.

Comment: Thanks! But i don't see the contradiction in this proof: $f(A' \cap A'') = \{ b \in B | \exists a: f(a) = b \wedge a \in A' \wedge a \in A'' \} = \{ b \in B | \exists a: f(a) = b \wedge a \in A' \} \cap \{ b \in B | \exists a: f(a) = b \wedge a \in A'' \} $

Comment: $\exists a[P(a)\wedge Q(a)]$ implies $\exists aP(a)\wedge\exists aQ(a)$ but converse is not true.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Try proving it 2 steps. First step 
$$f^{-1}(B'\cap B'')\subseteq f^{-1}(B')\cap f^{-1}(B'')$$
and the next step
$$f^{-1}(B')\cap f^{-1}(B'')\subseteq f^{-1}(B'\cap B'').$$
Let us consider the first step a bit closer. You prove such a thing by picking an element of the left hand side, say let $x\in f^{-1}(B'\cap B'')$. Then $x$ has some properties:
$$f(x)\in B'\mbox{ and } f(x)\in B''.$$
This in turn means
$$x\in f^{-1}(B') \mbox{ and } x\in f^{-1}(B''),$$
which gives you
$$x\in f^{-1}(B')\cap f^{-1}(B'').$$
Try the other step in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

$$x \in f^{-1}(A \cap B) \iff f(x) \in A \cap B   
\iff f(x) \in A \wedge f(x) \in B \iff$$$$
x \in f^{-1}(A) \wedge x \in f^{-1}(B)  
\iff x \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$$